# How to display plots in Jenkins of measured durations from tests in C++ over multiple builds

Tags: c++, boost, jenkins, boost-test, ctest

I have multiple test cases which actually measure the duration of a calculation using Boost timers.

The test cases are defined using Boost Test.

For running the tests I use CTest since I use CMake.
The tests are all specified with add_test().
Since CTest generates XML files I can display the Unit Test results in a corresponding Jenkins job.

For the performance tests I do not only want to display if the test cases succeeded but also the measured durations.

Is it possible in C++ (with Boost Test/CMake) to somehow mark measured durations and to convert them into a file which contains pairs for the test cases with two columns?

```
unittest0.dat:
test case | time
bla0        10 s
bla3        40 s
```

Then I would like to display this file and all similar files from previous builds in Jenkins as a plot.
The user should be able to follow the measured values over multiple jobs from the past to see if the performance has improved.

Therefore Jenkins would have to convert the data into files like:

```
bla0.dat:
build number | time
0              10 s
1              15 s
2              20 s
```

Maybe there is a complete different approach I don't know about.

Comment: Wow. Is that one sentence? [reference](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/has-anyone-really-been-far-even-as-decided-to-use-even-go-want-to-do-look-more-like)

Comment: @sehe Yes, yes indeed.